# Argument to get margin width for line

Tags: rules, width

I am typing up a homework assignment and am trying to separate the problem from the solution using a line.  For example right now I have

[image]

by using

```
\textbf{Problem 1 -} Chapter 5: 31, 35, 36, 38, 39, 41
\\
\line(1,0){470}
\\
```

I was wondering if there was some argument that could span the width between the margins without having to estimate that it's 470.  This is more of a curiosity thing, but it would still be nice to know if an argument like that existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\noindent\hrulefill
```

to have a rule filling the width of the current line *on the baseline*. A similar result is achieved using

```
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}
```

where `.4pt` is the default width of a rule. The second option allows you to adjust the vertical position using

```
\noindent\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<height>}
```

Note the use of `\noindent` which starts a paragraph and removes any indentation. Also, the use of `\linewidth` is encouraged, which could change if you're inside a list, whereas `\textwidth` is fixed, regardless of the setting.

Here are some examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text

\noindent\hrulefill

Some text

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}

Some text

\noindent\rule[.35\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{itemize}
  \item An item

  \hrulefill

  \item Another item

  \rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}

  \item Final item

  \rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, `Some text` always has an indent equivalent to `\parindent` since it starts a paragraph, while the items in the list have no (`0pt`) `\parindent`; so there's no need for `\noindent` (although it is useful in some cases).